# Playwright - Select element based on CSS property

Tags: css, playwright, playwright-dotnet

I need to select the appropriate element with Playwright by filtering based on CSS properties. In my particular case, I need to filter out the elements that have the `text-decoration:line-through` property and focus on the rest of them.

Here is the DOM with the elements:

```
<span>
    <span style="line-height:1.15 !important;display:initial;text-decoration:line-through;display:block;">0.42</span>
    <span style="line-height:1.15 !important;display:initial;font-weight:bold;">0.29</span>
</span>
```

(Terrible HTML code, I know... There is not much I can do about that though...)

In this case, I need to select the 2nd `span`, which is missing the strike-though style, but the order and number of `span` elements could not be anticipated.

Is there a way to do this with a single `ilocator.Locator(selector);` query?
I need to do it with a single query, because the code I create needs to be generic and not assume things and do "manual" filtering. Everything needs to be in the selector.

Comment: If you provide a bit more context, there may be a better way to select this than a chunk of the `style=` property.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the contain operator "*=". it should be something akin to:

```
page.locator('span[style*="text-decoration:line-through"]')
```

Demo in `CSS`:

```css
span {
  color: orange;
}

/* target span with line-through */
span[style*="text-decoration:line-through"],
/* handle white space */
span[style*="text-decoration: line-through"] {
  color: blue;
}

/* target span without line-through */
span:not([style*="text-decoration:line-through"]),
/* handle white space */
span:not([style*="text-decoration: line-through"]) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<span>
  <span style="stuff">a</span>
  <span style="stuff; text-decoration:line-through; foo">b</span>
</span>
```

Comment: This is interesting, because I have not thought of this, but there are two problems: 1) this includes the elements I want filtered out instead of excluding them and 2) there could be issues with spaces around the `:` character. In theory it could work though. I could instead use the `font-weight:bold` as part of the selector to solve the 1st problem and hope nothing changes in the spaces for the 2nd one.

Comment: @user2173353 edit to handle include/exclude and an example to handle a space after like `: `

Comment: Thanks. This should work. Initially, I was hoping there was something that was not relying on text-matching, but perhaps this is good enough. :)